# Is there any significant benefit to keeping shared network folders inside a VM rather than just mapping direct NAS folders?

Tags: windows, network-share, network-attached-storage

I'm working on a new storage plan and am wondering if there is any significant benefit to keep shared network folders inside of a VM.

Currently, our user shares (shared network drives) are simply a large 2nd disk in a Windows 2008 R2 virtual machine with the following drives (both on the same iSCSI LUN datastore):

- Disk 1: 60GB Virtual Disk - Contains OS files
- Disk 2: 2TB Virtual Disk - Contains folders that are shared on the network.

We have a new Synology NAS that I'm setting up which will replace our aging SAN, so it will have at least one iSCSI LUN created. Is there any reason why I *should* keep the user shares as something inside a VM? It seems like it would make more sense to just create a Synology Shared Folder and keep user shares on there.

Benefits of using a Large disk within the VM:

- ???.... Maybe file permissions management?
- Easier to run WinDirStat or WizTree/TreeSize (WizTree/TreeSize's super-fast mode doesn't like network drives)

Benefits of using a NAS shared folder for User Shares:

- Logical separation of duties
- Makes snapshots/backups of the VM smaller, thus allowing for faster recovery
- Allows recovery of user data separate without potentially rolling back changes to any host OS.

Note: I am also planning on moving to DFS Namespaces in the future, so whatever I do here should keep that goal in mind.

General Info: Mixed Windows/Linux environment for servers, 100% Windows for user workstations. Will be using AWS Glacier for off-site backups either via the built-in Synology Glacier Backup package or via Veeam (or both).

Cross-posted on [/r/sysadmin](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/8lm69g/is_there_any_significant_benefit_to_keeping/?ref=share&ref_source=link).

Comment: where did you read about "shared network folders inside of a VM". Also this question is bad as not asking something specific, i.e. "i have problem X how can i solve it, i tried YWZ"

Comment: you can ask "how do i optimize data storage for X", where X=problem that WizTree is solving

Comment: @aaaaaa I didn't "read about" a shared network folder inside a VM - it's what the previous sysadmins set up. And WizTree has nothing to do with my question. Did you actually read the full question? I do concede that my question is more of a "best practices" or "touchy-feely" question than a "problem-solution" type thing.

Comment: apologies, i think i misread your question

Comment: No worries, it happens! :-)

Comment: All I can think of is the permissions. I mean, that's the reason we do it that way in our Windows only environment. That and maybe some other file server nifty features (file filtering and the like).